# Theano error after pip install

Tags: gcc, installation, anaconda, theano

I have been trying to get Theano as backend for Keras on my 32-bit Windows 10. I have installed a bunch of different things, such as CUDA and Python 3.5 (I have 3.6.5 as my default) and even installed with Anaconda. The Anaconda download wasn't there when I used pip freeze in my terminal, and my code didn't recognize it after the conda install, so I simply pip installed Theano, which always gives me this error when I run it. I normally use Atom, not Anaconda, so I'm not sure if a conda install doesn't work for Atom. I am also unsure of how to switch my code in Atom to Python 3.5, as I know Theano only works up to 3.5, or if it's even necessary. I had previously installed my g++ gcc compiler through MinGW, which I have a suspicion might be the culprit for this error as well, as similar errors on StackOverflow questions had to do with this. The error is listed below. This has been a nightmare installation process, so I apologize for all the info about everything I've been doing. Help would be much appreciated.

Also, when I import Keras in my terminal with python 3.5, it says there is no such module.

Something is horribly wrong.

The error:

```
Using Theano backend.

You can find the C code in this temporary file: C:\Users\AARONM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\theano_compilation_error_9whx6ow7
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Aaron Mazie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\lazylinker_c.py", line 75, in <module>
    raise ImportError()
ImportError

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Aaron Mazie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\lazylinker_c.py", line 92, in <module>
    raise ImportError()
ImportError

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Aaron Mazie\Desktop\tradingbots\testntrain6.py", line 11, in <module>
    from keras.layers.core import Dense, Activation, Dropout
  File "C:\Users\Aaron Mazie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\keras\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import utils
  File "C:\Users\Aaron Mazie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import conv_utils
  File "C:\Users\Aaron Mazie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\conv_utils.py", line 9, in <module>
    from .. import backend as K
  File "C:\Users\Aaron Mazie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\__init__.py", line 81, in <module>
    from .theano_backend import *
  File "C:\Users\Aaron Mazie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\theano_backend.py", line 7, in <module>
    import theano
  File "C:\Users\Aaron Mazie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\theano\__init__.py", line 110, in <module>
    from theano.compile import (
  File "C:\Users\Aaron Mazie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\theano\compile\__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from theano.compile.mode import *
  File "C:\Users\Aaron Mazie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\theano\compile\mode.py", line 11, in <module>
    import theano.gof.vm
  File "C:\Users\Aaron Mazie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\vm.py", line 673, in <module>
    from . import lazylinker_c
  File "C:\Users\Aaron Mazie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\lazylinker_c.py", line 127, in <module>
    preargs=args)
  File "C:\Users\Aaron Mazie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\cmodule.py", line 2359, in compile_str
    (status, compile_stderr.replace('\n', '. ')))
Exception: Compilation failed (return status=1): In file included from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\math.h:36:0,
.                  from C:\Users\Aaron Mazie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\include/pyport.h:194,
.                  from C:\Users\Aaron Mazie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\include/Python.h:53,
.                  from C:\Users\Aaron Mazie\AppData\Local\Theano\compiledir_Windows-10-10.0.16299-SP0-Intel64_Family_6_Model_142_Stepping_9_GenuineIntel-3.6.5-32\lazylinker_ext\mod.cpp:1:
. c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\cmath:1157:11: error: '::hypot' has not been declared
.    using ::hypot;
.            ^~~~~
.
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone wondering, I uninstalled everything, including the Theano cache files manually, and watched this vid: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J70j6q7aOi4&t=131s&index=1&list=LLwpbw2KREgJdXEC0gLRTy4g